# Table with one border

Tags: html, css

Table with only one border line, in this case i have two borders...

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="88%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Add the border-collapse CSS rule:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8GQmb/)**

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use css for styling where possible. A great article about it is here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Try adding this to you css

```
 table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

An example is here http://jsfiddle.net/cxmBW/1